# A field should not be present according to an condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an enum status:

```
enum status: [ :x, :y , :z ]
```

Each status has model attributes that only relate to the selected status.

How would I validate that if the status is 'x' that the attributes related to 'y' and 'z' are blank?  And simiar validations are needed for status 'y' and status 'z'.

I want to validate that only the fields (attributes) that relate to the selected status are present.

Comment: unclear what you're asking

Comment: @MatheusSilva If you want to ensure that model has always only one status then it is added by design - in database status is an integer number, so it can equal to only one value - http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `absence` in `validates`

```
validates :x_attribute, absence: true, if: "status != 'x'"
validates :y_attribute, absence: true, if: "status != 'y'"
validates :z_attribute, absence: true, if: "status != 'z'"
```

It works for multiple attributes if you want.

```
validates :x_attribute_1, :x_attribute_2, :x_attribute_3, absence: true, if: "status != 'x'"
```

Comment: no_presence should work and is an alias for `absence` (I have edited my answer to use `absence` as it's clearer).  Basically it means that the attribute `:x_attribute` must be blank when the `if:` condition is true.